# Terminal (Ctrl+alt+F1-6) text colour

Tags: command-line, system, tty

Is it possible to change the default foreground text coulour in the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd> Terminals or the machines bios colour? I Love Green on Black and change it in the konsole/uxterm/Term etc as soon as I install the OS. But is it possible on the tty Pure Shell terminals  ie. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> etc.

Answer (score 1):

You must learn color escapes and bash prompt contruction.

For this follow this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_Bash_Prompt